# Unable to resolve module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault`

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli

When creating a new [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/) project using the standard `react-native init MyApp` and running `react-native run-ios` for the first time, I'm seeing the following error :

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` from `/Users/chrisedgington/Development/ReactNative/SixNationsPredictor/index.js`: Module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` does not exist in the Haste module map

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/chrisedgington/Development/ReactNative/MyApp/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:209:1301)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/Users/chrisedgington/Development/ReactNative/MyApp/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:83:16)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/chrisedgington/Development/ReactNative/MyApp/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:238:485)
    at Object.resolve (/Users/chrisedgington/Development/ReactNative/MyApp/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:180:25)
    at dependencies.map.result (/Users/chrisedgington/Development/ReactNative/MyApp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:311:29)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (/Users/chrisedgington/Development/ReactNative/MyApp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:307:16)
    at /Users/chrisedgington/Development/ReactNative/MyApp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:164:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/Users/chrisedgington/Development/ReactNative/MyApp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:266:307)
```

I've tried running the suggested, but still see the same issue. I've seen a few posts about similar issues, but nothing specifically seems to say how to resolve the problem in React Native.

```
macOS: 10.13.6 
node: 8.11.3
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.57.1
```

Answer (score 209, accepted):

Have a go and try:

`npm add @babel/runtime`

Or upgrade babel runtime:

`"@babel/runtime": "7.0.0-beta.55"`

Comment: Looks like the issue has been logged https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21310

Comment: was banging my head with this error since 2 days.. got resolved in 2 mins... many thanks @jrk

Comment: @CKT - that's what stackoverflow is for :)

Comment: It's not working for me. new react-native project always fails with this error

Comment: @th3g3ntl3m3n make sure you restart the metro builder after installing the package.

Comment: I still have this error when I am using `class { ... }` somewhere in my code. When I remove it everything works. Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Why happens this? :(

Comment: It worked for me with `npm start -- --reset-cache` after install `@babel/runtime`.

Comment: May I know what this error is indicating and how this solution works for this?

Answer (score 18):

I tried all the things mentioned above, and, I found myself here again tonight.

Running from a nrwl mono repo, I had to cd into the app that was having the problem and run.

`jest --clearCache`

Comment: This one helped me

Comment: In case you don't have or don't want to install jest globally, `npx jest --clearCache` worked for me too

Answer (score 10):

You should first quit the metro terminal before executing

```
npm add @babel/runtime
npm install
```

Answer (score 9):

You should add and install babel for your projects

```
npm add @babel/runtime
npm install
```

If The error is not fixed, Try:

```
npm start --reset-cache
```

Comment: for my case this resolve the issue `npm start --reset-cache`

Comment: This did the trick for me! Thanks!

Comment: npm start --reset-cache

 worked for me as well

Comment: For me I used 'npx react-native start --reset-cache'

Answer (score 6):

The issue for me was that @babel/runtime was installed as a dev-dependency instead of just a normal (non-dev) dependency

Comment: Thanks! This solved the error for me too! Make sure to also delete relevant caches and throw away package-lock.json and node_modules before you run npm i.

Comment: How to fix it??

Answer (score 5):

Current error message suggests these steps to fix this:

1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
2. Delete node_modules: rm -rf node_modules and run yarn install
3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*

The last one solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

try to add :

```
npm add @babel/runtime
```

then

```
 pod install
```

and everything will work

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your npm version first

`npm update -g npm@version` or `sudo npm -gf update npm@version`

and then just add the babel runtime at your react native project

`npm add @babel/runtime`

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading your packages. You could have an old package causing the problem:

```
yarn upgrade-interactive --latest
```

Comment: This is the only answer that solved it for me

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem today (April 2021), and I could solve it only by removing the `webpack-node-externals` package from my webpack configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally deleted my **node_modules** and **package-lock.json**. I used `npm i` to regenerate them and suddenly I was getting the above error. I solved it in two ways.

1. By uninstalling the app and using the following commands.

   `npx jest --clearCache`

   `npm update`

   `npm i`

   `npx react-native run-android`
2. By deleting the local repository and re-cloning it.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Someone may find this helpful. I had the same problem while using turborepo and Expo.
Resolved it by adding 'node-linker=hoisted' to .npmrc.

Answer (score 0):

**For me the solution was (Mac):**

1. Stop IntelliJ
2. Enter terminal
3. Run: `npx browserslist@latest --update-db -g`
4. Run: `npm cache verify`
5. Start IntelliJ

**If still not working:**

1. Delete node_modules fron project if exists
2. Run: `npm cache verify`
3. Run npm install -f in project
4. Run: `npx browserslist@latest --update-db -g`

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

I was in the middle of upgrading **flow to typescript** and I used `@khanacademy/flow-to-ts` to convert js files to ts. the lib not only changed the js files of the app but also it converted all js files in `node_modules` directory.

**Solution:**

I had to remove the `node_modules` and `npm -i`. This time when I checked the `node_modules` the `interopRequireDefault.js` file was there.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are working with **Yarn workspaces** please note you are running `react-native start` from the right project...

Answer (score 0):

**Install latest Babel/runtime**
=> install @babel/runtime

**After that clean or reset the cache**
=> npm start -- --reset-cache after
or
npm cache clean --force

Answer (score 0):

I just uninstalled watchman. It worked for me.

```
brew uninstall watchman
```

Answer (score 0):

**FOR REACT NATIVE IN 2023!**

If you're working on a react-native project and face this or a similar error, cd into your ios folder and run pod install

`cd ios`

`pod install`

Then, start your metro server and run the project again.

Comment: Thank you! My problem was that I did a lot of fiddling around in the Xcode project with the release builds, after starting the bundle server.

On top of restarting the server, I had to do a `watchman watch-del-all` but not it works :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case node_modules was a symlink (to /opt/node_modules). Removing the symlink and recreating node_modules as a directory helped.

Answer (score -1):

Had this issue none of the above listed solutions worked for me, I had to go to `node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js`

changed `const crawl = canUseWatchman && this._options.useWatchman ? _watchman.default : _node.default;`

to `const crawl = canUseWatchman && this._options.useWatchman ? _node.default : _node.default;`

Comment: It's never a good idea to change something in the node_modules folder..