# Jest - Cannot find module '.../node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault'

Tags: node.js, npm, jestjs, babeljs

I am trying to run my project's tests on my CI/CD machines.  They are jest tests that have been running fine for some time on all my environments.  I am going through package updates, and somewhere along the way, I began having issues.  I see that every test is failing because if this error:

```
 ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '/cicduser/myproject/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault' from 'src/setupTests.ts'

      1 | /*
      2 |  * Filename:       setupTests.ts
    > 3 |  * Classification: UNCLASSIFIED
        |                              ^

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-runtime/node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:306:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/setupTests.ts:3:30)
```

This is happening on a Debian Ubuntu-16 linux instance, with node 14.16.3 and npm 8.1.0.

This is *not* happening my local machine.  My local machine runs these tests just fine.  My local is a mac Catalina 10.15.7, and I've tried versions of node 14 and 16, as well as npm 7 and 8, and no issues.  I did read [Unable to resolve module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52486219/unable-to-resolve-module-babel-runtime-helpers-interoprequiredefault), as well as a number of other related questions, but no solution is helping.  I have tried

- `npm install @babel/runtime`
- `npm install babel-preset-react-app`
- adding `"nohoist": ["**/babel-preset-react-app/@babel/runtime"]` to package.json
- uninstalling and reinstalling all packages a few times over with various variations of this

Its a little befuddling that the tests work fine on my laptop, with all variations of what I've tried above, and fail on my CI/CD instance, with all variations of what Ive tried above.

What can I do to debug this?  Why would this issue persist, despite trying the best answers and suggestions as described above?

Comment: I have the same situation but in total reverse: all my tests pass on the dev server I'm deploying to via Azure but they all fail for me locally with the same error you're showing.

Comment: @LCIII I ended up nuking my entire fleet of CI/CD instances and rebuilding them with Ubuntu-20.  I also upgraded to node@16 and npm@8.  After doing all that, that seemed to help.  Not very practical for you I guess, but perhaps upgrading node and npm would help?

Answer (score 20):

Try to clear jest cache

```
jest --clearCache
```

or

```
npm run test -- --clearCache
```

Comment: this issue happened to me after i `rm -rf` my node_modules and reinstalled them. solution works, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue but opposite: it would work on my Azure pipeline but fail locally. I got all tests to run successfully in both environments after running this:

```
npm i babel-preset-react-app@7.0.0
```

Based on this issue: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6398#issuecomment-462475835

The user ( [jeremyckahn](https://github.com/jeremyckahn) ) who posted it said this:

> I was able to work around this issue with:
>
> `npm i babel-preset-react-app@7.0.0`
>
> The latest version as of this writing is 7.0.1. It appears that something related to #6393 is causing this issue.
>
> Relevant commits:
>
> b02f181#diff-5a51074922f8107dc611b7e125130e7e
>
> b7e0158#diff-5a51074922f8107dc611b7e125130e7e

Answer (score 0):

The same was happening to me and downgrading to `babel-preset-react-app@7.0.0` fixed it, per the same suggestion above.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this locally on Windows by using a symbolic link to `node_modules`

```
mklink /D .\node_modules C:\NodeJs\node_modules
```