# Unable to resolve module 'module://@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault.js' - EXPO SNACK

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, babeljs

I am getting the error **'Unable to resolve module 'module://@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault.js**' when I try to run the following code in Expo Snack

Below is my code for HomeScreen.js

```js
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList } from "react-native";
    import axios from "axios";
    import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    
    export default function HomeScreen() {
      const [cycles, setCycles] = useState([]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
          try {
            
    
            const { data: response } = await axios.get(
              "URL"
            );
    
            setCycles(response);
           
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(error.message);
          }
          
        };
    
        fetchData();
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {/* <Text> {JSON.stringify(cycles[0])} </Text>   */}
          <FlatList
            data={cycles}
            renderItem={(
              { item } //this part will iterate over every item in the array and return a listItem
            ) => (
              <Text>
                {new Date(item.startDate).toLocaleDateString("us-EN")} -{" "}
                {new Date(item.endDate).toLocaleDateString("us-EN")}{" "}
              </Text>
            )}
          />
          <Text>Hello</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
```

And below is App.js

```js
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList } from "react-native";
    import axios from "axios";
    import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";
    import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
    import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
    
    const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
    
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Home"
              component={HomeScreen}
              options={{ title: "Welcome" }}
            />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    }
```

Package.json file

```js
    {
      "dependencies": {
        "react-native-paper": "4.9.2",
        "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
        "expo-constants": "~13.2.4",
        "axios": "*",
        "@react-navigation/stack": "*",
        "@react-navigation/native": "6.0.0",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
        "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0"
      }
    }
```

[image]
From one of the questions I found [Unable to resolve module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52486219/unable-to-resolve-module-babel-runtime-helpers-interoprequiredefault),  I tried adding babel and it has not worked.(ie it throws another error as below)
[image]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7):

Downgrade axios to `0.27.2` to align with Expo built-in @babel/runtime version.

Answer (score -2):

Running `npm add @babel/runtime`
and then `npm install` solved my issue.