# Build single JS file with babel

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I have a react app that I build using Vite, but at the same time I have single `.js` file that i want to compile before Vite build.
Inside this single `.js` file just vanilla JS with ES5 syntax. I'm trying to build him using babel with this command:

`npx babel widget/scripts/api.js --out-dir widget/api --presets=@babel/preset-env --no-babelrc`

After building i get the following error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

Babel put this part at the start of compiled script:

```
"use strict";

var _interopRequireDefault = require("@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault");
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.Api = void 0;
var _classCallCheck2 = _interopRequireDefault(require("@babel/runtime/helpers/classCallCheck"));
var _createClass2 = _interopRequireDefault(require("@babel/runtime/helpers/createClass"));
```

Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Refer :https://stackoverflow.com/a/19059825/1356109

Comment: I don't have any imports in my script before babel build

Comment: refer this then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52486616/1356109 , its similar issue

Comment: doesn't help. anyway thank you! i guess i will just use vite for  build single file, screw this error :)